Trying to use the document_ocr Drupal module to process HEIC image files
Right now I am thinking that the Google Document AI processor can process iPhone images. If I select this processor, does the document_ocr Drupal module convert HEIC image files to JPeg before it feeds it to the processor?
Thanks ahead!
I tried tesseract and was unimpressed with accuracy.
